# Enable local administrator account for clients from server 2008

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, powershell

I ran into a problem with one of my client , its local administrator account is disable, also I can't log in this machine with its domain user (because of [this problem](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162797)), now I wanna change its administrator local account from my server(DC). Is there any way to do that via CMD , Powershell or something like that? or Is it Possible?
**Thanks in Advance.**

Comment: Have you tried deleting the computer account on the DC, then booting into safe mode to reset the local admin password? If you can do that, then you can rejoin the domain and continue on your merry digital way.

Comment: I don't have access to that computer, I just want to do that remotely.

Comment: Is RDP enabled on that computer?

Comment: `net user administrator /active:yes` is the cmd you are looking for, however you need to be able to do that on the computer that requires it.
Without access directly to the computer, i'm not entirely sure how you could go about it. 
PSEXEC is a program which will allow you to run commands on a remote computer, but it still requires some form of functioning user account on that particular machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have admin rights on that computer (either with a local account or a domain account), how do you expect to do that? Which utility you use is not important.

The only possible way I can think of is to delete and recreate or reset the computer account on your domain, and then reboot the remote machine (though, if you don't have admin rights, you might not be able to do that either).

If what I suggested is irrelevant or not working than you better get physical access (and then use HBCD or WinPE to reset local administrators password).
Or you can hire a hacker...